# Nothing is shown after php-include

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to include a php-file in another one (as the very first thing), because I need the variables, which are results of an MySQL-Statement. Here is the file whith the include:

index.php:

```
 <?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL); //No errors are shown
    require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."php/db/acp_settings_db_conn.php");
    echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; //doesn't work
    ?> /*  * some html code, which isn't shown either  */
```

this is the file which get's included:

```
<?php
//Get configuration values (static) from file
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."acp_settings_db_conf.php");
//Create new object out of connection to db
$db = @new mysqli(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS, MYSQL_DB);
//If there aren't any errors
if(mysqli_connect_errno() == 0){
    //Write query, in this case get every row from table
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `meta`';
    //If you could prepare query
    if($meta_settings = $db->prepare( $query )){
        //Execute query
        $meta_settings->execute();          
        //Bind results to custom variables
        $meta_settings->bind_result($html_language, $site_author, $site_keywords);  
        //Fetch result
        $meta_settings->fetch();
    } else { //If you couldn't prepare query
        echo "There is a problem with the query";
    }

} else { //If you couldn't connect to DB at all
    die("No connection possible: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
//Close connection
$db->close();
?>
```

The included file works pretty well (checked it with echos), now the include is working aswell (if I have something echoed in the included file, it pops up on the index.php). But after the include, nothing else is shown. So no  php-code is working, nor any html is shown.
I tried an include 'file.php', but that did not work aswell.

So since I spend my evening on this, I'd be happy if someone could help me. Those are my first steps in PHP, so be gentle ;)

Comment: Did you try deleting the `<?php` in your included file?

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL)` is not enough. Make sure you `ini_set('display_errors', true)` too.

Comment: Hey,@fedorqui: That did not work, the browser just showed the code. @Mathieu Imbert: Didn't know I would need ini_set aswell. Got two nice errors, they are fixed now and it's working. Thanks :)

Comment: @stiller_leser You are welcome. Don't forget to remove it when going live. You don't want to publicly show these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "php/db/acp_settings_db_conn.php");
```